# How to findout main method has called by JVM or existing process?

Tags: java

Considering the following code

```
public static void main(String...arg){
//do something
if(<<the method has called by a new process>>){System.exit(0);}
else{System.setProperty("main_result","0");return;}
}
```

the main method would be called by a separated process by JVM or existing process, now how can I find it out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clarify: there might be another class with a `main` that was started, or the `main` is somehow called again.

Normally you want to call `System.exit(0)` (or `return;`?) but when called from the program itself you want to end in `System.setProperty("main_result","0");`.

```
public static void otherMain(String[] args) {  
    Main.main(args);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {  

    ...

    StackTraceElement[] elems = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    //for (StackTraceElement elem : elems) {
    //    System.out.printf("%s%n", elem.getClassName());
    //}
    if (elems.length > 2) { // [0] Thread [1] main
        System.setProperty("main_result","0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, well I just tested this solution myself, but what if user hacks the stack by reflection or overrides the default runtime(`rt.jar`) package?

Comment: `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` should help there; see Javadoc. Checking the class loader should help too for security purposes. There is not much that can be done for hiding a caller. (Cross my fingers)

Answer (score 1):

> In java, every Java process runs in its own JVM. So, the "same" main
>   method cannot be called by a different process under normal
>   circumstances
>
> Even if you run the same program twice, they will be running in their
>   own JVMs.
>
> You can try one thing.. Keep a static variable in your program, run it and
>   make it sleep for a long period of time (process 1).. Now, run the same
>   program again and update the static variable(runs in process 2).. See, whether it will be
>   updated in the first process (No, it won't be updated as each process will have it's own
>   set of variables..)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need it? Just don't use `System.exit(0);` and refactor `main` method to finish gracefully.

Calling `System.setProperty` in both cases - when run as new process and also as a class on classpath, will not make any difference.

Edit: Finding out who is calling the method is not easy and definitely bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the code as follows:

```
public static void main(String...arg){
  System.exit(doStuff(arg));
}

public static int doStuff(String... arg) {
  //do something
}
```

To access this logic within the same JVM you can now call `MyClass.doStuff` and get the return value directly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to consider refactoring and get rid of such problem.

Otherwise the following code can help:

```
    if(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName().equals(
            System.getProperty("sun.java.command"))){
        System.out.println("!");
    }
```

Will not work if there is no "sun.java.command" property (on not Sun/Oracle JVMs it may absent)